# Implementing rotors

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

How can I pattern match 2 strings in Haskell? Like let's say I have one string which is all the alphabets `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"` and another string `"EKMFLGDQVZNTOWYHXUSPAIBRCJ"`. It's like a ciphering thing, where I want to pattern match both these strings so that when I type HELLO in plain text using the normal alphabets, I get `"QLTTY"`.

Comment: What relevant stuff were you looking for?

Comment: Like all I found online was how to pattern match a string to characters that you manually code to match it. But I do not want to manually code the 2nd string, I want it to be like having 2 strings and then pattern match them. The thing is, I have several ciphered strings, in which the plain text alphabet can match to so manually coding the second string in which I want to cipher the plain text string input by the user won't be such a good idea because then it means for every single Ciphered string in which I have 5, it would be a very long code. I'm trying to do an Enigma machine in Haskell.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Apologies if it wasn't such a good description to what I'm looking for as I find it hard sometimes to speak my mind but I tried. Also it'll take me a lot of time if I would have to brutally code the second string which is my cipher string to match all the letters in the alphabet.

Answer (score 2):

Let's save these strings so we have some convenient names.

```
a = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
b = "EKMFLGDQVZNTOWYHXUSPAIBRCJ"
```

Now if you `zip` them together you get a lookup table.

```
ghci> cypher = zip a b
ghci> cypher
[('A','E'),('B','K'),('C','M'),('D','F'),('E','L'),('F','G'),('G','D'),('H','Q'),('I','V'),('J','Z'),('K','N'),('L','T'),('M','O'),('N','W'),('O','Y'),('P','H'),('Q','X'),('R','U'),('S','S'),('T','P'),('U','A'),('V','I'),('W','B'),('X','R'),('Y','C'),('Z','J')]
```

You now simply need to `map` your string to a lookup on this cypher.

```
map (\ch -> ...) "HELLO"
```

This should give you a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: I see, this is using functions zip and map. But what if I want to use pattern matching and return the indexes of the characters? How can I do that? Due to the knock-on position of the rotors whereby when the rotors reach a certain character on the alphabet, it triggers the next rotor's offset up by 1 hence I think I would still prefer to use pattern matching to match the characters on the alphabet with the characters on the rotors... @Chris

Comment: If you want to write your own lookup function that uses pattern matching to iterate over both strings in parallel: `lookup ch (x:xs) (y:ys) = if x == ch then ... else lookup ch xs ys`. You'd also need to handle not finding the input character. `lookup _ [] [] = ...`